# How do I iterate over a categories field in an entry

Tags: craft3, plugins

I'm using the Scout plugin to sync my entry data to an Algolia search index. In the transformer for the scout.php config file, I need to iterate over all of the categories in a category field on each entry.

How would I do this to output the category at each level like so:

```
"categories": {
    "lvl0": ["Rigging", "Film Lighting"],
    "lvl1": ["Rigging > Rigging Support", "Film Lighting > Stands"],
    "lvl2": ["Rigging > Rigging Support > Stands"]
}
```

Here is where i'm at with the transformer:

```php
'transformer' => static function (craft\base\Element $entry) {
    return [
        'entryTitle' => $entry->title,
        'id' => $entry->id,
        'url' => $entry->url,
        'title' => $entry->equipmentFriendlyName,
        'manufacturer' => $entry->equipmentManufacturer,
        'modelNumber' => $entry->equipmentModelNumber,
        'description' => $entry->equipmentDescription,
        'categories' => $entry->equipmentCategory->all(),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

````php
<?php
return [
    'transformer' => function(craft\base\Element $entry) {
        $level1Categories = [];
        $level2Categories = [];
        $level3Categories = [];

        foreach ($entry->equipmentCategory->level(1)->all() as $category) {
            /** @var $category \craft\elements\Category */
            $level1Categories[] = $category->title;
            $children           = $category->getChildren()->level(2)->all();

            foreach ($children as $child) {
                /** @var $child \craft\elements\Category */
                $crumb      = [
                    $category->title,
                    $child->title,
                ];

                $level2Categories[] = implode(' > ', $crumb);

                foreach ($child->getChildren()->level(3)->all() as $subChild) {
                    /** @var $subChild \craft\elements\Category */
                    $crumb      = [
                        $category->title,
                        $child->title,
                        $subChild->title
                    ];

                    $level3Categories[] = implode(' > ', $crumb);
                }
            }
        }

        return [
            'entryTitle'   => $entry->title,
            'id'           => $entry->id,
            'url'          => $entry->url,
            'title'        => $entry->equipmentFriendlyName,
            'manufacturer' => $entry->equipmentManufacturer,
            'modelNumber'  => $entry->equipmentModelNumber,
            'description'  => $entry->equipmentDescription,
            'thumbnail'    => !empty($entry->equipmentImages->one()) ? (string)('https://acsweb.com' . $entry->equipmentImages->one()->getUrl()) : '',
            'categories'   => [
                'lvl0' => $level1Categories,
                'lvl1' => $level2Categories,
                'lvl2' => $level3Categories,

            ],
        ];
    },
];```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through `equipmentCategory` and compile the array that you want.

```php
$categories = [];

foreach ($entry->equipmentCategory->all() as $category) {
    $categories[] = /* However you want to configure the category */;
}

return [
    ...
    'categories' => $categories,
];
```

You may even want to offload this logic to a separate `private` method, to keep things a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Fred Carsen's approach, but it didn't quite output what I expected. Here's my approach:

```php
// get categories
$level1Categories = [];
$level2Categories = [];
$level3Categories = [];

foreach ($product->productFamily->level(1)->all() as $category) {
    $level1Categories[] = $this->traverseCategory($category);
}
foreach ($product->productFamily->level(2)->all() as $category) {
    $level2Categories[] = $this->traverseCategory($category);
}
foreach ($product->productFamily->level(3)->all() as $category) {
    $level3Categories[] = $this->traverseCategory($category);
}    

// ...

return [
    // ...
    'productFamilies'   => [
        'lvl0' => $level1Categories,
        'lvl1' => $level2Categories,
        'lvl2' => $level3Categories
    ]            
];

// ...

private function traverseCategory($category){
    $parent = $category->parent;
    if ($parent != null){
        return $this->traverseCategory($parent) . ' > ' . $category->title;
    }
    else {
        return $category->title;
    }
}
```

As I had to poke a lot around to find info on this, I've included the entire SiteModuleService that creates the Algolia Indicies and scales a product image. Perhaps it is helpful for someone else:

```php
<?php
/**
 * site-module module for Craft CMS 3.x
 */

namespace modules\sitemodule\services;

use modules\sitemodule\Sitemodule;

use aelvan\imager\Imager;
use aelvan\imager\services\ImagerService;
use craft\helpers\UrlHelper;

use Craft;
use craft\base\Component;
use craft\commerce\Plugin;

class SitemoduleService extends Component
{

    public function getIndicies(){
        $indicies = [];
        $productTypes = Plugin::getInstance()->getProductTypes()->getAllProductTypes();

        // iterate product types and create one index for each type
        foreach ($productTypes as $productType){

            $indicies[] = 
            \rias\scout\ScoutIndex::create(getenv('ENVIRONMENT').'_products_'.$productType->handle)
                ->elementType(\craft\commerce\elements\Product::class)
                ->criteria(function (\craft\commerce\elements\db\ProductQuery $query) use ($site, $productType) {

                    $query->siteId = $site->id;
                    $query->typeId = $productType->id;

                    return $query;
                })
                ->transformer(function (\craft\commerce\elements\Product $product) {
                    return $this->transformProductData($product);
                });
        }

        // create one indice that contains all products
        $indicies[] = 
        \rias\scout\ScoutIndex::create(getenv('ENVIRONMENT').'_products')
            ->elementType(\craft\commerce\elements\Product::class)
            ->criteria(function (\craft\commerce\elements\db\ProductQuery $query) use ($site) {

                $query->siteId = $site->id;

                return $query;
            })
            ->transformer(function (\craft\commerce\elements\Product $product) {
                return $this->transformProductData($product);
            });        

        return $indicies;
    }

    private function traverseCategory($category){
        $parent = $category->parent;
        if ($parent != null){
            return $this->traverseCategory($parent) . ' > ' . $category->title;
        }
        else {
            return $category->title;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Transformer used by Scout to feed Algolia with Product data
     */
    public function transformProductData(\craft\commerce\elements\Product $product){

        $supplier = (string)$product->supplier[0]->title;

        // get categories
        $level1Categories = [];
        $level2Categories = [];
        $level3Categories = [];

        foreach ($product->productFamily->level(1)->all() as $category) {
            $level1Categories[] = $this->traverseCategory($category);
        }
        foreach ($product->productFamily->level(2)->all() as $category) {
            $level2Categories[] = $this->traverseCategory($category);
        }
        foreach ($product->productFamily->level(3)->all() as $category) {
            $level3Categories[] = $this->traverseCategory($category);
        }        

        $ret = [
            'title' => $product->title,
            'url' => $product->url,
            'productDescription' => $product->productDescription,
            'image' => $this->getProductPrimaryImage($product), 
            'supplier' => $supplier,
            'productFamilies'   => [
                'lvl0' => $level1Categories,
                'lvl1' => $level2Categories,
                'lvl2' => $level3Categories
            ]            
        ];

        // return data to algolia                
        return $ret; 
    }

    public function getProductPrimaryImage(\craft\commerce\elements\Product $product){

        // generate product image
        $srcImage = $product->productImage->one();

        // found any?
        $imageUrl = "";

        // get base URL of site 5
        $baseUrl = rtrim(UrlHelper::siteUrl("","","", 5),'/');

        if ($srcImage){

            // get focalpoint
            $focalPoint = $srcImage->getFocalPoint();
            if (!$focalPoint) {
                $focalPoint = "50% 50%";
            }

            // transform with imager
            $image = Imager::getInstance()->imager->transformImage($srcImage, [
                'width' => 400,
                'format' => 'jpg',
                'ratio' => 1/1,
                'allowUpscale' => false,
                'jpegQuality' => 90,
                'position' => $focalPoint,
                'interlace' => true
            ], null, null);
            $imageUrl = $baseUrl.$image->url;                            
        }
        else {
            $imageUrl = "https://via.placeholder.com/400x400.png?text=Placeholder";
        }  
        
        return $imageUrl;

    }
}
```

It gets called by `scout.php` thus:

```php
'indices' => (new \modules\sitemodule\services\SiteModuleService)->getIndicies()
```